# updating records from controller in web2py

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, web2py

I want to update some field in a record of database form controller given i know which record that is and which field that is.How do i do that?

Eg:In the table 'students' in the database there is field called gender which is either 'male' or 'female'.After adding many  records,i add a new field called 'gender_description'.It should be 'girl' when gender is female and 'boy' if gender is male.I want to populate this new field for all the records automatically.How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In a web2py shell, you can do:

```
db(db.students.gender == 'male').update(gender_description='boy')
db(db.students.gender == 'female').update(gender_description='girl')
```

You don't want to do this in the app code, because the above should be run only once. Also, make sure the "gender_description" field has already been added to the model definition and that a migration has been run (this will happen automatically as long as migrations are enabled).

Note, if there is always a one-to-one correspondence between "gender" and "gender_description", this may not be the best database design.

As an alternative, you might consider creating a [virtual field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#New-style-virtual-fields) in web2py:

```
db.define_table('students',
                Field('gender', ...),
                Field.Virtual('gender_description',
                              lambda r: 'boy' if r.gender == 'male' else 'girl'),
                ...)
```

Comment: i  found the answer(this is working)
db(db.table.gender=='female').update(gender_description='girl')
db(db.table.id=='male').update(gender_description='boy')

we can write this in controller itself

Comment: No, don't put that code in the controller. That will unnecessarily update every record in the table on every request to that controller, even though you only really need to do the updates once. You can put that code in a controller, but then you should delete it after the first time it runs, as it will no longer be necessary after that.

Comment: i meant to ask this question because i wanted to automate changing some field(a single field in a single record ) in the database.So to automate this i think this is the best way.As for the above example concerned i agree with you

Comment: So, this is the correct answer to the question you actually asked but not to the question you meant to ask instead?